# Angular Material custom form field component circular dependency injection error

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I've been trying to create a custom form field control using Angular material.
I need it to work with both Reactive Forms and NgModel.

I've been following this documentation from Angular Material: https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control

The component is working as expected when using NgModel. But when I change over to using Reactive forms the `Validate` method from the `Validator` interface is never called.

The class implements the following interfaces:

```
export class MaterialMultiSelectComponent implements MatFormFieldControl<any[]>, ControlValueAccessor, Validator, OnDestroy
```

In the providers section, I have added this, as suggested in the documentation.

```js
providers: [
        {
            provide: MatFormFieldControl,
            useExisting: MaterialMultiSelectComponent
        },   
    ]
```

But I found this: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/

```
Notice that without registering this class properly in NG_VALIDATORS,
the validate method will never get called.
```

But if I do add `NG_VALIDATORS` to the providers, like this:

```js
providers: [
        {
            provide: MatFormFieldControl,
            useExisting: MaterialMultiSelectComponent
        },
        {
            provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => MaterialMultiSelectComponent),
            multi: true
        },
    ]
```

I get a circular dependency error

```
Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for MaterialMultiSelectComponent
```

What am I missing?

Comment: is it possible to provide a simple stackblitz with the issue replicated?

Comment: I've encountered the same issue where a CircularDependency issue popped up when combining `MatFormFieldControl` with `NG_VALIDATORS`. As annoying as it is, I ended up splitting the `MatFormFieldControl` from my custom form component and applied it as a hostDirective (or use a similiar selector as my custom form component)

This would be akin to a similiar approach as `input` and `matInput`, where `matInput` is the MatFormFieldControl and `input` would be like our custom form component. 

I know it's not much help, but that's how I ended up solving this problem